# PHP Zend - Execute to get a rowset and total number of records

Tags: php, mysql, row

I encounter some problem where i want to execute a SQL statement and get the total number of records + all the records.

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ProjectID = 1 ";
$stmt = $db->query($strSQL);
$total = count($stmt->fetchAll());
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    ..No More Record Shown here..
}
```

but there is no more record in the while loop after i execute fetchAll, i believe I need to get back to the first row or something, anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Agreed with Asaph, you should just store it in a variable and iterate through it. For your total number of records, you can just echo $total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already fetched all the records with `fetchAll()`. So when you call `fetch()`, there are no more records to read. Try storing the return value of `fetchAll()` in a variable and iterating through that. Something like this:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ProjectID = 1";
$stmt = $db->query($strSQL);
$allRows = $stmt->fetchAll();
$total = count($allRows);
foreach ($allRows as $row){
    // process each $row
}
```